# How to filter out info by using useDelimiter

Tags: java, arraylist, jcombobox

So, what am I trying to do is I get the info from a text file,

```
      For example, 134567H;Gabriel;24/12/1994;67;78;89
```

Then I display **only Admin number which is the first one but not the whole line** in drop down list. So here are my codes :

```
    public static String[] readFile(){
    String file = "output.txt";
    ArrayList <String> studentList = new ArrayList <String> ();
    try{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);
    sc.useDelimiter(";");

    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        studentList.add(sc.nextLine());
    }

    fr.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException exception){
        System.out.println("File " + file + " was not found");
    }catch(IOException exception){
        System.out.println(exception);
    }
    return studentList.toArray(new String[studentList.size()]);
}
```

And this is how I populate the drop down list :

```
    public void populate() {
    String [] studentList ;
    studentList = Question3ReadFile.readFile();

    jComboBox_adminNo.removeAllItems();

    for (String str : studentList) {
       jComboBox_adminNo.addItem(str);
    }
}
```

However, my problem now is the options in drop down list is showing the whole line from the text file. It is not showing the admin number only. I tried with useDelimiter already. Am I supposed to use that?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Rince help check.**

```
    public class Question3ReadFile extends Question3 {

private String adminNo;

public Question3ReadFile(String data) {
    String[] tokens = data.split(";");
    this.adminNo = tokens[0];
}

public static String[] readFile(){
    String file = "output.txt";
    ArrayList <String> studentList = new ArrayList <String> ();
    try{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);

    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        studentList.add(new Question3ReadFile(sc.nextLine()));
    }

    fr.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException exception){
        System.out.println("File " + file + " was not found");
    }catch(IOException exception){
        System.out.println(exception);
    }
    return studentList.toArray(new String[studentList.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hasNext and next instead of hasNextLine and nextLine

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String input = " For example, 134567H;Gabriel;24/12/1994;67;78;89";
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
     scanner.useDelimiter(";");
     String firstPart = null;
     while(scanner.hasNext()){
         firstPart = scanner.next();
         break;
     }

     String secondPart = input.split(firstPart)[1].substring(1);
     System.out.println(firstPart);
     System.out.println(secondPart);
     scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: But this just split out the whole row from text file into 6 options. I  am trying to do like I select the admin number then all the info from that chosen admin number of that row will be displayed in text box.

Comment: @Rauryn I do not understand anything. Can you re-phrase it?

Comment: Sorry for my English. So, I chose an admin number, then the rest of the info would be displayed in other places. According to your code, it just simply split out the whole row into several options.

Comment: @Rauryn so you want to split it in: 134567H AND Gabriel;24/12/1994;67;78;89? If not tell me how you need it

Comment: Ya I am trying to do like that. Then later part I will try to split the rests of the info and assign them into correct text boxes

Comment: I getting array index out of bound exception error. Hold on, let me try to check out for the errors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28441/discussion-between-eugene-and-rauryn)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use delimiter in this case. I suggest to make a Student object out of the line.

```
studentList.add(new Student(sc.nextLine));
```

and have the Student class:

```
public class Student {
    private final String adminNo;

    public Student(String data) {
        String[] tokens = data.split(";");
        this.adminNo = tokens[0];
    }


    public String getAdminNo() {
        return adminNo;
    }
}
```

and then you just read the fields you need later (student.getAdminNo()) for example.

This approach is much prettier and easier to extend later.

**upd: simplistic approach**

Or don't bother with stupid OO and just do this:

```
studentList.add(sc.nextLine.split(";")[0]);
```

Comment: Where is the "new Student" comes from? Because there is an error at the "add" there. Can you please kindly explain to me? Is it a class name?

Comment: Modified the answer. Now including the super awesome Student class

Comment: I modified my post, Can you help me check what's wrong with my codes? I getting error at the add there.

Comment: Updated. Remove the original solution and just use the line provided :)

Comment: Wow. It works. Thanks a lot. But your updated one only apply to split the first item only right? It doesnt work to split the rests of the item

Comment: .split(";") splits it into an array and you can access the elements by index ([0] in case of the first one)

Comment: So if I want to split the whole row of info into 6 different parts, I should do this : String[] parts = sc.nextLine().split(";");
String part1 = parts[0]; 
String part2 = parts[1];
...
Is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: And yeah, easy ways would be with providing indexes, prettier and harder ways are with annotations and mappings.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to finish it up.